# How to change the tag column selection option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have a tag column in the active admin index page like

```
tag_column :result, interactive: true, sortable: false
```

in my model I have a enum for result as

```
 enum result: { winner: 0, first_runner_up: 1, second_runner_up: 2}
```

In the index page when I click on drop down the selection options are being dispalyed as

**winner**

**first_runner_up**

**second_runner_up**

How can we display them as

**Winner**

**First Runner Up**

**Second Runner Up**

Can someone please help...
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you break the rules out to a hash.. then you will be free to validate against them later

```
WINNER_OPTIONS = {
  winner: {
    title: "Winner"
  },
  second: {
    title: "First Runner Up"
  },
  third: {
    title: "Second Runner Up"
  }

RESULT_ENUMS = WINNER_OPTIONS
  .keys
  .with_index
  .to_h

enum result: RESULT_ENUMS

tag_column :result, WINNER_OPTIONS.values.map{|e| e[:title]}.with_index.to_h
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a helper method that will get the result and return the data as per your format?

Add a Helper method in your active admin model  for displaying the enum values in your format

in your active admin model file

```
tag_column :result, interactive: true, sortable: false do |#your_model|
    modify_data(your_model.result)
  end
```

helper method like this to customize the display of the names of your result

```
def modify_data(result)
    case result.to_sym
    when :winner
      'Winner'
    when :first_runner_up
      'First Runner Up'
    etc.. 
  end
```

end